# Is it possible to load limited columns with pandas for processing but output with entire columns though

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working with pandas to process very huge csv files lately, and the read_csv(..) itself is taking more time than the actual processing. I am not able to figure out if its possible to read only few columns from the csv for the task that I am doing so my read_csv would be faster?
My task involve reading two CSVs and concatenate them by doing the following:

1. Take one of the column from both and change them to something which is defined in a method `def resolver(series_1, series_2)`. This is done by doing the `csv2_df[that_col] = csv1_df[that_col].combine(csv2_df[that_col], resolver)`.
2. Concatenate csv1 with csv2 preferring csv2 for the intersecting rows: `result_df = pd.concat([csv1_df[~csv1_df.index.isin(csv2_df.index)], csv2_df])`
3. Remove rows that are marked for deletion in the 1st step: `result_df = result_df[result_df[that_col] != '$Delete']`
4. result_df.to_csv(...)

- Note: Before these steps, my read_csv(..) for those two files resembles the following: `pd.read_csv(input_file, sep='\x1D', engine='python', skiprows=1, skipfooter=1, header=0, dtype=str, keep_default_na=False)`

**EDIT:**
Reproducible code:

```
csv2_df = pd.read_csv(csv2, sep='\x1D', engine='python', skiprows=1, skipfooter=1, header=0, dtype=str, keep_default_na=False)
csv1_df = pd.read_csv(csv1, sep='\x1D', engine='python', skiprows=1, skipfooter=1, header=0, dtype=str, keep_default_na=False)
csv2_df.set_index(primary_idx_list, inplace=True, verify_integrity=verify_integrity)
csv1_df.set_index(primary_idx_list, inplace=True, verify_integrity=verify_integrity)

def resolver(v1, v2):
    return '$Delete' if v1 == 'A' and v2 == 'B' else (v1 if v1 == 'A' and v2 == 'C' else (v2 if pd.notna(v2) else v1))

csv2_df[that_col] = csv1_df[that_col].combine(csv2_df[that_col], resolver)
result_df = pd.concat([csv1_df[~csv1_df.index.isin(csv2_df.index)], csv2_df])
result_df = result_df[result_df[that_col] != '$Delete']
result_df.to_csv(...)
```

Comment: The method `read_csv` has an argument [usecols](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#:~:text=of%20each%20line.-,usecols,-Sequence%20of%20Hashable)

Comment: It is possible to load only selected columns, this will take less memory but pandas will still have to parse the whole file. Please provide a [mre] of the data if you want specific suggestions.

Comment: @mozway, updated with minimal reproducible code

Comment: @MatthiasMertens, I know it has one, but not able to figure out how to fit that into my use case...

Comment: @SpaceyBot that's not reproducible, I don't have `csv2` on my computer. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464).

Comment: that's just a file name you should have in your path. the reason I am stressing more on the read_csv(..) parameter and not do it in accordance to what's available in your link is to indicate the complexity of the parameters such as multi-char separator, dtype=str, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up your read_csv by reading only necessary cols

```
import pandas as pd

# Define the columns you want to read from the CSV files
# Assuming 'unique_id' is the column you use to uniquely identify rows
# and 'that_col' is the column you need to process
columns_to_read = ['unique_id', 'that_col']

# Modify your pd.read_csv() calls to include `usecols`
csv1_df = pd.read_csv('input_file1.csv', sep='\x1D', engine='python', skiprows=1, skipfooter=1, header=0, dtype=str, keep_default_na=False, usecols=columns_to_read)
csv2_df = pd.read_csv('input_file2.csv', sep='\x1D', engine='python', skiprows=1, skipfooter=1, header=0, dtype=str, keep_default_na=False, usecols=columns_to_read)

# Your processing steps remain the same
def resolver(series_1, series_2):
    # Your resolver function implementation
    pass

# Assuming 'unique_id' is set as the index if it's not already
csv1_df.set_index('unique_id', inplace=True)
csv2_df.set_index('unique_id', inplace=True)

csv2_df['that_col'] = csv1_df['that_col'].combine(csv2_df['that_col'], resolver)

# Concatenate csv1 with csv2 preferring csv2 for the intersecting rows
result_df = pd.concat([csv1_df[~csv1_df.index.isin(csv2_df.index)], csv2_df])

# Remove rows that are marked for deletion
result_df = result_df[result_df['that_col'] != '$Delete']

# Write the result to a new CSV file
result_df.to_csv('output_file.csv', sep='\x1D', index=True)
```

Comment: I think this will have only the `index` and `that_col` in the output_file.csv... but after the processing, I would want resulting csv to contain every other columns and data too.